# Números primos não são listados

Tags: c, array, algoritmo

Estou tentando criar um programa em C que mostre todos os números primos de 1 a 100 usando força bruta, porém meu programa mostra nada na tela.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x=100,n=2,z=0;
    int p[z];
    verif:
    while(x!=1)
    {
        while(x%n!=0)
        {
            if(n==(x-1))
            {
                z++;
                p[z-1]=x;
                break;
            }
            n++;
        }
        x--;
        n=2;
        goto verif;
    }
    while(z>=0)
    {
        printf("%d",p[z]);
        z--;
    }
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

O maior problema é que seu *array* tem zero elementos, acho que você queria trabalhar com 100 deles.

Vamos simplificar o código?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int p[100];
    int z = 0;
    for (int x = 100; x > 1; x--) {
        for (int n = 2; x % n != 0; n++) {
            if (n == x - 1) {
                p[z++] = x;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (z >= 0) printf("%d ", p[z--]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iSql8Z). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dwofaboz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/DeclareSize.c).

Comment: Ficou bem mais fácil de entender, realmente simplificou bastante o código. Que interessante, você fez um repositório para as respostas do **Stack**, acho que vou começar a fazer isso também, tenho alguns arquivos soltos aqui que usei para formular resposta, acredito que vai facilitar a organização. :D